# Is it possible to run two scripts, one after the other, from one HTML button?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have Google Sheets sidebar code that provides the user with a simple form to fill in and submit the data to a named range. A second function is then run to execute a program that uses the date stored in the named range.

At the moment I have two buttons in the side bar - one "SubmitRecord()" submits the record and the second "allFuntions()" executes the function that does stuff with the data.

This is the line of code in the sidebar HTML:

```
<input type="button" value=" Set Configuration " onclick="SubmitRecord()" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Is it possible to execute the two functions one after the other in the 'onclick' part of the code?

Comment: You might need to use SpreadsheetApp.flush() between the first and the second to insure that the data has been saved completely.

Comment: About `Is it possible to execute the two functions one after the other in the 'onclick' part of the code?`, I think that in your situation, it is required to know the script of `SubmitRecord()` and `allFuntions()`. Because when these scripts are run with the asynchronous process, it is required to prepare the script for running with the synchronous process.